# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion, closing

[Why does Clairvoyance always point me in the wrong direction?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/47106/10036)

The question that I asked was trying to figure out why clairvoyance didn't work properly most of the time. the question that was chosen for a duplicate was asking if clairvoyance would boost illusion and what the point of double casting the spell was.

How are these two questions similar with the exception that they are just about the same spell?

Comment: Seems that what you linked was a duplicate and that it's been answered.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the one who initiated the Duplicate vote to close, primarily because of Cor_Blimey's excellent and detailed answer (note: It's **Not** the accepted answer), which seems like it does answer your question.

Comment: I also voted to close it. The way I saw it was that asking about a specific aspect of Clairvoyance - why it was misleading you at times - was covered by the existing question about how it works, and particularly by the answer mentioned above. The fact that the answer for the newer question is essentially copied and pasted from the existing question seemed to confirm the duplication.

Comment: exactly, Cor_Blimey's answer covers the new question, I don't see why it was reopened frankly.

Comment: Agreed.  Duplicates don't need to be exactly corresponding, one can be a subset of the other.  If the question you have is answered by another, it shouldn't matter whether the question you post is open.

Comment: Ahhh, okay. That explains it. Sometimes I'm dumb and misstep. :x